# app-scripts library corrupted my Ionic config

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I tried to install app-scripts and I get this error. It messed up my environment and I can't use `ionic serve` any more.

```
$ npm install @ionic/app-scripts --save-dev
ionic-hello-world@ /home/louisro/Documents/mobileApps/BoardLine/ionic2_version
├── @ionic/app-scripts@1.2.1 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.0.9

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @ionic/app-scripts@1.2.1 requires a peer of typescript@~2.2.1 but none was installed.


$ ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.2.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: Try npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest

Comment: refer this [starter app package.json](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json). Set it as 1.1.4

Comment: @SuryaTeja that's what messed up in the first place.

Comment: @suraj indeed it's 1.1.4 the right version, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm install app-scripts@1.1.4 --save-dev
```

solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got an `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY` try to pin typescript to the compatible version in your package.json.

> @ionic/app-scripts@1.2.1 requires a peer of typescript@~2.2.1 but none was installed.

Try to execute the following command after pinning the version to be sure `node_modules` are reinstalled `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install`